# API Platform does not recognize true environment variables

Tags: api-platform.com

I setup a brand new skeleton Symfony project and added the API Platform package. I created an entity with make:entity, created a migration, was able to *successfully* execute the migration, and can now see the table in my database.

From the API swagger documentation page (and via curl request in my local terminal), attempts to execute a basic GET request for all entity resources fails. The error appears to result from the API using the DATABASE_URL from the .env file, not the DATABASE_URL that exists as an actual environment variable. This is easy to see since the .env file is using MySQL whereas my actual environment variable is using PostgreSQL.

Executing `printenv` shows the proper value, `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` shows the proper value, and clearly Doctrine recognizes the proper environment variable because the migration executed successfully.

Furthermore, if I remove the DATABASE_URL line from the .env file, simply attempting to load the API results in a 500 error stating `Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL".`

What is causing the API Platform to ignore my environment variable while Symfony and Doctrine recognize it just fine?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem in the docker configuration. When using s6 overlay as a process supervisor, the services.d file that runs PHP needs to use the `with-contenv` helper in order to have environment variables available.

Replacing

```
#!/usr/bin/execlineb -P
php-fpm -R --nodaemonize
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/with-contenv sh
exec php-fpm -R --nodaemonize
```

allowed PHP to see the environment variables set within my docker-compose file and the API platform started returning results as expected.